# Android phone/tablet and computer does not recognize the 2d lidar connected by type-C

Tags: android, usb, smartphone

We are using a lslidar m10 which has a type C interface.
It can be connected to the USB A port on a computer and work fine.
[image]
Now we look to use the lidar with an android tablet/phone which only has a type C port.
But connecting the lidar to the phone does not work.

What is the cause for this problem?

Our attempts:
a. We connect the lidar to the type C port on the computer. The lidar's LED light does not turn on. And no response shows on the computer ports. To my knowledge, the type C port usually has a higher voltage level than USB A. So the voltage should not be a issue.
[image]

b. We connect the lidar to the USB A port on the computer, but the connection is achieved by a cable from type C port of the lidar to another type C, and then the USB A port. In this case, the lidar works fine.

[image]

c. We connect the lidar to the type C port on a smartphone which can be connected a USB hub and read from thumb drives on the hub. This time, the lidar does not work as in case a.

I has been in touch with the customer support of lslidar, but they just say we don't support type-C connection. I wonder why this is the case since we have all the necessary ingredient as shown by test case b.

I searched the internet for possible answers, esp. stackoverflow, but to no avail.
I expect to find the reason behind the problem so we may connect the lidar to the computer or a smartphone via the type C port.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a hardware question, so voting to close.  However, just because it has a USB connection doesn't mean that the device knows how to use it.  It generally needs drivers on the device to understand how to talk to the connected device.  I suggest asking about connecting the device on a hardware question site, then coming back here when you have it connected and are asking about accessing the USB device programatically.

Comment: OK. I will google and go for some hardware site.

Comment: I have migrated the question to [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/679210/android-phone-tablet-and-computer-does-not-recognize-the-2d-lidar-connected-by-t). This one can be safely closed.